# Count number of VMs based on Management Group names

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell, azure-resource-graph

I would like to create a Graph QL query or a Powershell script(preferred) that would display the Total number of VMs in all Azure subscriptions along with number of VMs in management groups containing a certain string and count of rest of the VMs under management groups which doesn't have that specific string

```
Resources
| where type =~ 'Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines'
| Count
| project TotalVMs=Count
```

Answer (score 0):

> Total number of VMs in all Azure subscriptions along with number of VMs in management groups containing a certain string and count of rest of the VMs under management groups which doesn't have that specific string.

> I have followed this [MS Doc1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/get-azmanagementgroup?view=azps-9.7.0) & [MSDoc2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/992897/powershell-script-to-getlist-of-all-vms-in-all-su) as a reference.
>
> Here is the `Powershell script` to display the total number of **VMs** in all **Azure subscriptions** along with number of **VMs** in`management groups` containing a certain string.

```
> Connect-AzAccount 
> Select-AzSubscription -All 
> $searchString = "vm"
> $mgmtGroups = Get-AzManagementGroup
> $totalVMs = 0 
> $matchingVMs = 0 
> $nonMatchingVMs = 0
> foreach ($mgmtGroup in $mgmtGroups) {
> Write-Host "Checking management group $($mgmtGroup.DisplayName)"
>     $vms = Get-AzResource -ResourceType "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines"
>     $vms.Name
>     $vmCount = $vms.Count
>     $totalVMs += $vmCount
>     if ($vmCount -gt 0) {
>         $matchingVMCount = ($vms | Where-Object { $_.Name -like "*$searchString*" }).Count
>         $matchingVMs += $matchingVMCount
>         $nonMatchingVMs += ($vmCount - $matchingVMCount)
>     }
>  Write-Host "Found $vmCount VMs in the management group"
>  Write-Host "Found $matchingVMCount VMs containing '$searchString'" }

> Write-Host "Total VMs in all subscriptions: $totalVMs" Write-Host
> "Matching VMs in Management Group: $matchingVMs" Write-Host
> "Non-matching VMs in Management Group: $nonMatchingVMs"
```

**Output:**

[image]